# Migration DB2 to MySQL using MySQL Workbench 6.2 5 Error

Tags: mysql, db2, mysql-workbench

### Does MySql workbench support the DB2 to MySql migration ?

Steps I followed :

1. Installed DB2 ODBC driver and and defined the conection parameters for my DB2 database in 'Source Selection'.
   I am using Database System as "Generic RDBMS" and Connection Method as "ODBC Data Source" and DSN with DB2 ODBC driver.
2. Defined the MySql database details in 'Target Selection'
3. When I do next and it goes to 'Fetch Schema List', I get error as below. Although my source and target database connection successful.

**Error logs from workbench as follows :**

> Starting...
>
> Connect to source DBMS...
>
> Connecting to source...
>
> Connection to apparently lost, reconnecting...
>
> Connecting to ...
>
> Opening ODBC connection to DSN=EESBPTS...
>
> Connected
>
> Connect to source DBMS done
>
> Check target DBMS connection...
>
> Connecting to target...
>
> Check target DBMS connection done
>
> Retrieve schema list from source....
>
> Checking connection...
>
> Connection to apparently lost, reconnecting...
>
> Connecting to ...
>
> Opening ODBC connection to DSN=EESBPTS...
>
> Connected
>
> Fetching catalog names...
>
> Fetching schema names...
>
> Fetching schema names from None...
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.2 CE\workbench\wizard_progress_page_widget.py", line 192, in thread_work
>
> self.func()
>
> File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.2 CE\modules\migration_source_selection.py", line 456, in task_fetch_schemata
>
> self.main.plan.migrationSource.doFetchSchemaNames(only_these_catalogs)
>
> File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.2 CE\modules\migration.py", line 255, in doFetchSchemaNames
>
> self.state.sourceSchemataNames.append("%s.%s" % (self._db_module.quoteIdentifier(catalog), self._db_module.quoteIdentifier(schema)))
>
> TypeError: DbGenericRE.quoteIdentifier(): argument 1 must be a string but is None
>
> ERROR: Retrieve schema list from source: DbGenericRE.quoteIdentifier(): argument 1 must be a string but is None
>
> Failed

**Please help me to proceed further.**

Comment: Can you try the latest WB version (6.3.9 atm.)?